# Render PDF on custom controller action using wicked_pdf

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, wicked-pdf

This may end up being very simple but I have been trying to figure this out to no avail. I am using wicked_pdf to render pdfs on html pages. When I do this the restful way by adding the respond_to block to a controllers show action everything works fine when going to controller/id.pdf.

What I am trying to do however, is use the respond_to block on a custom controller action. I have a reports controller which has many reports and custom actions. One of these reports has a form which is submitted to another custom controller action to render the report. This all works fine with the html render however, when I added the respond_to block to this custom action it simply tells me it cannot find the show action for that controller. Below is the related code:

routes.rb

```
resources :reports do
  collection do
    get 'customer_summary'
    post 'summary_report'
  end
end
```

reports_controller.rb

```
def summary_report
  @tickets = tickets
  respond_to do |format|
   format.html
   format.pdf do
    render pdf: "summary_report", header: {spacing: 10, html: {template: 'shared/header'}},   footer: {html: {template: 'shared/footer'}}, margin: { top: 20, bottom: 20 }
  end
end
```

The templates exsist as well as the summary_report.pdf.haml file. What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: have you tried appending `.pdf` in your route when accessing `summary_report`? as in `localhost:3000/reports/summary_report.pdf`. Also, why `post` instead of `get`?

Comment: customer_summary is a form that actions to summary_report so I had to use post for it to work. I guess I could change the form action method and that would work too. When i put .pdf on the end of summary report it gives me an error saying about the show action.

Comment: Try dropping the `respond_to` block, so the render pdf line comes right after @tickets.